# How should I fetch data in descending order from database according to the date_time?

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**
I have the last data entry in date_time for 9th of april 2013 whereas when I try to fetch in descending order from the database it is giving me 8th April 2013. Please see the image and Code below. Any help will be appriciated.

**Database**
[image]

**Code**

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_feeds
WHERE username =  'davidjhume@gmail.com'
AND gadget_data_type =  'Weighin'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( date_time,  '%D, %j %M %Y %H:%i:%s' ) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Do you really have date_time as a varchar field? If so change it to a datetime field, then just `ORDER BY date_time

Comment: what is the field type od  "date_time"? Is it varchar or date ?

Comment: Your format string looks totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format string is broken, try:
    '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s'

Answer (score 0):

Your format for str_to_date() is wrong
You say
`%D, %j %M %Y %H:%i:%s`
So according to you the second value is %j. But according to Mysql docs %j is 'day of year'. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

**edit**: you have multiple errors in the format. Try: `%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s`